# How to include/exclude many different files/folders using terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, find

I am doing a search for files that have been edited in the last day using the `find . -type f -mtime 0` function in terminal. I want to exclude some files and folders in the query, such as `.DS_Store` files and `.sh` files.

Currently I am doing this:

`find . -type f -not -path "*.DS_Store" -and -not -path "*.sh" -mtime 0`

I still have many more files I want to exclude, and I am wondering if it is possible to shorten the expression. I do not want to write:

`-not -path "PathHere" -and -not -path "AnotherPathHere"` and so on.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-and` is redundant regardless, so you can simply remove that, and `!` can be used instead of the non-standard `-not` operator. You can use a bash array to list the excludes one per line. Not much shorter, but easier to read and edit.

```
filters=(
    ! -name '*.DS_Store'
    ! -name '*.sh'
    ! -name '*.bash'
)

find . -type f \( "${filters[@]}" \) -print
```

Extending the above to also avoid descending into certain directories by using `-prune`:

```
filters=(
    ! -name '*.DS_Store'
    ! -name '*.sh'
    ! -name '*.bash'
)
prune_dirs=(
       -name '*.tmp'
    -o -name 'tmp'
    -o -name '.Trash*'
)

find . -type d \( "${prune_dirs[@]}" \) -prune -o -type f \( "${filters[@]}" \) -print
```

Comment: Ooh, bash array is a nice way to go!

Comment: Works like a charm for files. I try to exclude folders as well (e.g `! -name "*.tmp/*"` but it does not work. Do I have to adjust the code in order to exclude folders as well?)

Comment: @John `-name` only matches on the last path component. To match on the whole path, use `-path` like in your question. `! -path "*.tmp/*"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use standard Bash pattern matching, or [globbing](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html), within the find command, so you could use the `-iname` option (which is a case-insensitive name search) and `!` as the 'not' operator, so for the case you've posed:

```
find . -type f \( ! -iname ".DS_Store" ! -iname "*.sh" \) -mtime 0
```

Comment: Nice addition with the `-iname` instead of just `-name` :)

Comment: `-name` and `-path` take glob patterns, not regular expressions.